# Multi-Threaded Java Based Prime Number Generator

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, primes, cpu-usage

I am working on a prime number generator that is multi-threaded. My goal for this multi-threaded process is that each process will check a single number. I do have somewhat working code, but I am having some issues with the "locking" concept in where the schedular is running 2 process's very closely to each other.

```
Claimed Lock: 0; Claimed Number: 75827; isPrime: false
Claimed Lock: 1; Claimed Number: 75829; isPrime: false
Claimed Lock: 2; Claimed Number: 75831; isPrime: false
Claimed Lock: 4; Claimed Number: 75835; isPrime: false
Claimed Lock: 5; Claimed Number: 75837; isPrime: false
Claimed Lock: 5; Claimed Number: 75837; isPrime: false
Claimed Lock: 3; Claimed Number: 75833; isPrime: true
Claimed Lock: 6; Claimed Number: 75839; isPrime: false.
```

(you can see that 2 locks - i.e. 5 get called twice - they should be disctinct)

My main goal of this program is to have 1 thread calculate 1 based prime numbers. There will be n number of threads based on what Java JVM reports back to the int cores variable inside of the code.

**Here is a quick explanation of my program:**

1. The program starts out getting the number logical cpu cores of the given computer
2. Creates a 2d Array of [2] [Num of CPU Cores]
3. Array[0][i] = Gets filled with 2k+1 (odd numbers) of potential prime numbers (doing this since 2 is the only known prime number that is even)
4. Array[1][i] = Gets filled with "-1" = Meaning that number is ready to be picked up by a process/thread
5. The program then spins up n number of threads (based on cpu core count)
6. A new thread that has been created is supposed to look for the next available Array[1][i] == -1 and change it to the value of 2. (2 represents a process lock and/or the number is being checked if prime or not)

   -6a. The n number of child processes check if prime, and will change the Array[1][i] to either 1 or 0 (1 meaning it is prime or 0 meaning its not prime)

   -6b. Child Process Terminates
7. Parent process - Main will busy wait until all Array[1][i] is either 1 or 0
8. Repeat back to step 3

**What am I a missing or doing wrong with this logic? I believe I am missing something with the JVM/OS Schedular. But, I feel like I could be incorrect in this assumption as well? What could I do to remedy this issue?**

Here is my Code:
Multi-Threaded Class

```
class MultithreadCalculate extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            int indexNum = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.cores; i++) {
                if (MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[1][i] == -1) {
                    MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[1][i] = 2;
                    indexNum = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[0][indexNum]; i++) {
                if (MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[0][indexNum] % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[1][indexNum] = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime) {
                MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[1][indexNum] = 1;
            }

            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "; Claimed Lock: " + indexNum + "; Claimed Number: " + MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[0][indexNum] + "; isPrime: " + isPrime);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class MultiThreadPrimeNumGen {
    public static int[][] primeArray;
    public static int primeBase = 1;
    public static int cores;

    private static void fillArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
            primeBase += 2;
            primeArray[0][i] = primeBase;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
            primeArray[1][i] = -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop" + "/PrimeNumber.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);

        //Gets number of CPU Cores
        cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println("Number of Cores: " + cores);

        while (true) {
            primeArray = new int[2][cores];
            fillArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                MultithreadCalculate multithreadCalculate = new MultithreadCalculate();
                multithreadCalculate.start();
            }

            while (true) {
                boolean flag = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                    if ((primeArray[1][i] == 0) || (primeArray[1][i] == 1)) {
                        flag = true;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                if (primeArray[1][i] == 1) {
                    out.println("PrimeNum: " + primeArray[0][i]);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any locking at all. Why shouldn't two threads see the same -1 at the same time?

Comment: I think my current knowledge of Concurrent Programming is a little off. I guess I thought implemented (step 6 in the list above) was considered a locking mechanism. what is a good resource for a good fundemental understanding?

Comment: You can check out the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) for a basic introduction to synchronization. Java Concurrency in Practice is a great book for more in-depth study.

Comment: Also, I just want to say thank you very much for the Documentation!!

Answer (score 0):

So you want *thread* at the loop while filling the array:

```
Runnable run1 = new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
       // Code to fill array
    }
};

Thread thread1 = new Thread(run1);
thread1.start();

Runnable run2 = new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
       // Code to fill array
    }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread2(run2);
thread2.start();
```

Comment: Could you further elebaborate on this? I guess I am a little confused on what this is meaning? Do you want me to "fill the array" when a new process is spawned?

Comment: You know that program runs line to line. You required a code which runs continously seperate from the main program or say thread. So the void fllArray() can be used in thread so that is runs continously

Comment: hahah I'm aware that programming runs line to line. The parent process just sets the objects with a specific number and then they will start calculating them if their prime or not. The goal was for this project to just infinitely run in a  loop... aka just keep calculating the prime numbers until the 32bit integer limit is reached.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I solved my own idea without using Locks. The Idea Came from another user who posted on here: Prime Balpreet. So thank you! What I did was create getters and setters inside of the code. Here is the Modified code:

Multithreaded Class:

```
class MultithreadCalculate extends Thread {
    int PrimeNumCalculate = -1;
    int indexNum = -1;

    public int getPrimeNumCalculate() {
        return PrimeNumCalculate;
    }

    public void setPrimeNumCalculate(int primeNumCalculate) {
        PrimeNumCalculate = primeNumCalculate;
    }

    public int getIndexNum() {
        return indexNum;
    }

    public void setIndexNum(int indexNum) {
        this.indexNum = indexNum;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < getPrimeNumCalculate(); i++) {
                if (getPrimeNumCalculate() % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[0][getIndexNum()] = getPrimeNumCalculate();
                    MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[1][getIndexNum()] = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime) {
                MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[0][getIndexNum()] = getPrimeNumCalculate();
                MultiThreadPrimeNumGen.primeArray[1][getIndexNum()] = 1;
            }

            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "; Index: " + getIndexNum() + "; Number: " + getPrimeNumCalculate() + "; isPrime: " + isPrime);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Main Class:

```
public class MultiThreadPrimeNumGen {
    public static int [][] primeArray;
    public static int primeBase = 1;
    public static int cores;

    private static void fillArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
            primeArray[0][i] = -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
            primeArray[1][i] = -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop" + "/PrimeNumber.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);

        cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println("Number of Cores: " + cores);
        out.println(2);
        out.flush();
        while (true) {
            primeArray = new int[2][cores];
            fillArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                MultithreadCalculate multithreadCalculate = new MultithreadCalculate();
                multithreadCalculate.setPrimeNumCalculate(primeBase += 2);
                multithreadCalculate.setIndexNum(i);
                multithreadCalculate.start();
            }

            while (true) {
                boolean flag = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                    if ((primeArray[1][i] == 0) || (primeArray[1][i] == 1)) {
                        flag = true;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            printMatrix(primeArray);

            for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
                if (primeArray[1][i] == 1) {
                    out.println(primeArray[0][i]);
                }
            }

            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] arr) {
        if (null == arr || arr.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        int idx = -1;
        StringBuilder[] sbArr = new StringBuilder[arr.length];
        for (int[] row : arr) {
            sbArr[++idx] = new StringBuilder("[\t");
            for (int elem : row) {
                sbArr[idx].append(elem).append("\t");
            }
            sbArr[idx].append("]");
        }
        for (StringBuilder stringBuilder : sbArr) {
            System.out.println(stringBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```